# Newly installed openladp - error: no such object for dc=example,dc=com

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I am following the [Ubuntu guide for openldap server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html). After installation I'm trying to inquire the new example database it was suppose to create.

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=com dn
```

Which returns:

```
No such object (32)
```

Is the installation does not create the example.com entry ? How do I create it ?

Answer (score 0):

The installation did not populated dc=example,dc=com into LDAP

You need to create it. [refer](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-populate)